# Dynamic Getters and Setters - Why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, getter-setter

I'm trying to create an object that builds its own getters and setters dynamically:

```
function Person( properties ) { // 'properties' is an object literal

    this._private = properties; // private by convention

    for ( key in this._private ) {

        this[key] = function() {

            return this._private[key];
        }
    }
}
```

**I hoped, this would create something like this:**

```
var jack = new Person({

    working:true,
    age:33,
    gender:'male'
});

jack.working() --> true
jack.age() --> 33
jack.gender() --> 'male'
```

**The problem is, it always returns 'male'**, like so:

```
jack.working() --> 'male'
jack.age() --> 'male'
jack.gender() --> 'male'
```

**What am I missing?** Oh, and this is just a proof of concept. I know this is not a perfect solution for creating getters and setters in JavaScript.

Comment: I know this is not your question, and you might already be aware, but it would improve the code if you put a 'var' in the for loop, i.e.: for ( var key in this._private ) { ... }. Otherwise the 'key' variable will be created in your global scope (or even worse: any existing variable will be overwritten).

Comment: @Maate You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a classic scoping issue. Create a new function to create scope around `key`:

```
function Person(properties) { // 'properties' is an object literal
    var key;

    this._private = properties; // private by convention
    this.buildGetter = function (key) {
        this[key] = function () {
            return this._private[key];
        }
    };
    for (key in this._private) {
        this.buildGetter(key);
    }
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/SEujb/

Comment: Explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Dang, I was completely missing the scoping pitfall.

Comment: So he does not need to write `return this`? :O

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I meant at the end of function Person.

Answer (score 3):

Everybody says eval is evil, but sometimes it can't be avoided:

```
function Person( properties ) { // 'properties' is an object literal

    this._private = properties; // private by convention

    for ( key in this._private ) {

        eval("this[key] = function() { return this._private['"+key.toString()+"'];}");
    }
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pitaj/9sWbe/1/

Comment: Although the answer by AndrewWhitaker is probably better for this instance.

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use `eval` here.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I never said there was. I said there may be some instances where there is no other way.